# Interdependent component which need to communicate each other

Tags: javascript, angular

I am in a situation like i have 5 interdependent component which need to communicate each other. For example if i click on a button A on all other 4 component need to listen to the click and alert something. The same way button in other component also listened by all other 4. Need a best solution on how to achieve this.

here is my code snippet

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonService } from 'broadcast-recive/service/common-service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-broadcaster',
  templateUrl: './broadcaster.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./broadcaster.component.css']
})
export class BroadcasterComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private commonservice: CommonService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  broadCastMe(): void
  {
    this.commonservice.btnClickedInBroadCasterComponent((<HTMLButtonElement>event.target).id);
  }

}

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonService } from 'broadcast-recive/service/common-service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-listener1',
  templateUrl: './listener1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./listener1.component.css']
})
export class Listener1Component implements OnInit {

  constructor(private commonservice: CommonService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.commonservice.clickStatusForBroadCastercomponentBtn.subscribe((id: string) => {
      alert('alert from listner 1');
    })
  }

}

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonService } from 'broadcast-recive/service/common-service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-listener2',
  templateUrl: './listener2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./listener2.component.css']
})
export class Listener2Component implements OnInit {

  constructor(private commonservice: CommonService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.commonservice.clickStatusForBroadCastercomponentBtn.subscribe((id: string) => {
      alert('from listner 2');
    });
  }

}
```

Here am always getting alert box "from listener 2 " , My requirement is its should trigger both the listener. Please help me refactoring the code. blow is my service where am using rx js for subscribing.

```
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class CommonService {

  public clickStatusForBroadCastercomponentBtn = new Subject<string>();
  public clickStatusForBcomponentBtn = new Subject<string>();

  btnClickedInBroadCasterComponent(btnId: string): void {
    this.clickStatusForBroadCastercomponentBtn.next(btnId);
  }
  btnClickedInComponentB(btnId: string): void {
    this.clickStatusForBcomponentBtn.next(btnId);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this Angular (2+) or AngularJS (1.x)? Do you mean related components (parent hosts component selector DOM) or unrelated (no parent to host selector DOM)? Have you viewed the basic component interaction page https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [rxjs Subject](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/subject.md) declared in a service. Lets say, you have a service named AService:

```
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject;

@Injectable()
export class AService {

  public clickStatusForAcomponentBtn = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
  public clickStatusForBcomponentBtn = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');

  btnClickedInComponentA(btnId: string): void {
    this.clickStatusForAcomponentBtn.next(btnId);
  }
  btnClickedInComponentB(btnId: string): void {
    this.clickStatusForAcomponentBtn.next(btnId);
  }
}
```

Now, you can use this service in all your components those need to communicate with each other like this:

```
 export class AComponent implement OnInit {
     constructor(private aService: AService){}
     ngOnInit(){
        this.aService.clickStatusForBcomponentBtn .subscribe((clickedBtnId:string)=> {
           // whenever button with id clickedBtnId clicked in Component B this observer 
           // will be get executed.So, do your necessary operation here.
        }
     }
     btnClickListenerForA(event:Event){ /* in this component template you'll bind this listener with your button click event */
        this.aService.btnClickedInComponentA((<HTMLButtonElement>event.target).id);
     }
 }

 export class BComponent implement OnInit {
     constructor(private aService: AService){}
     ngOnInit(){
        this.aService.clickStatusForAcomponentBtn .subscribe((clickedBtnId:string)=> {
           // whenever button with id clickedBtnId clicked  in Component A this observer 
           // will be get executed.So, do your necessary operation here.
        }
     }
     btnClickListenerForB(event:Event){ /* in this component template you'll bind this listener with your button click event */
        this.aService.btnClickedInComponentB((<HTMLButtonElement>event.target).id);
     }
 }
```

If you review the code, you'll understand two subjects are used to pass communication between two component. This way, you'll able to communicate between any number of components.

Thus, you can declare a rxjs subject for every button and for listening any button's click event you've to subscribe that buttons subject in other components where you want to listen that buttons event.

Hope this will guide you in a right direction.

Comment: i have tired this but not meeting my requirement below am putting my code snippet based on your answer

Comment: thanks for the help, updated my question with code snippet please have a look and revert if possible.

Comment: You've to use different subject for different button click listener. You're using the same subject.

Comment: I've edited my code and updated it with `BehaviorSubject`.

Comment: Thank you for the update, i have made the changes but now in my listener component the alert is coming in page load itself. That means two time the alert coming from each component. 2 from listener1 and 2 from listener2. How to remove that. Sorry for more trouble

Comment: You can check whether id is empty or not:  `if(id) { console.log('listening from ........') }`

Answer (score 0):

You should use a shared service with a `BehaviorSubject` to emit any changes to any component listing to it please take a look at my answer **[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46614312/2602962)** I posted it like a few seconds ago on a similar question.